# payment system/sdk available for MVC? answer based on 1. error free, 2. efficient in performance, 3. most adopted technique

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, payment, payment-processing

Like in Title I wonder what payment system do you recommend to use?
Maybe some of existing systems are better than other (easier for implement for example)?

So far I've try only paypal sdk for c#. But what is your recommendation for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a personal preference, so take it for what it's worth. I've had great luck with [Chargify](http://chargify.com/). The [C# library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/chargify) works well, it supports subscriptions and reoccurring billing, coupon codes, discounts, and metered billing.

[Cheddergetter](https://cheddargetter.com/) is an alternative to Chargify that also has .NET libraries.

I've found both significantly easier than trying to get regular [Authorize.net](http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/csharp/) working, and prefer it over only accepting PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @mfanto I will try this for sure :)

Comment: Yep. Both have some nice analytics too, and easy to export the data into various accounting apps. You pay for it in transaction fees, but it's a) safe and b) easy, which is almost impossible to do both yourself.